# H2o Parser issue

Tags: h2o

Using H2o 3.16.0.4 to parse the Kaggle Toxic data classifier competition. The data is not getting parsed even after using parser as csv and separator as ",". Let me know if this is a product related bug or some configuration is missing.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is likely that the comment fields have too many newlines so unfortunately changing the separator will not help.

As a workaround you can import the csv with pandas using `pandas.read_csv()` (which parses correctly) (Note: it's not working in `data.table::fread()` either as [reported here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/2600)).

To use the data frame in H2O for modeling, you just need to convert the data frame to an H2O Frame (use `df = h2o.H2OFrame(my_pandas_frame)` in Python.

I've created a [JIRA ticket](https://0xdata.atlassian.net/browse/PUBDEV-2853) so that this issue is being tracked and worked on.

Comment: Thanks for the solution , importing through pandas dataframe also had the same issue if the new line characters are not removed, after removing these characters in pandas dataframe it could be  imported and parsed properly. This has helped me move ahead.